# How to create a timed video from still images with specific time between each image?

Tags: ffmpeg, mogrify

I want to create a video from still images. My images are:

- 1.jpg
- 2.jpg
- 3.jpg
- 4.jpg
- 5.jpg
- 6.jpg
- 7.jpg
- 8.jpg
- 9.jpg

Each of them I want to show for a specific duration, between 1-10 seconds:

- 1.jpg: 2 seconds
- 2.jpg: 6 seconds
- 3.jpg: 10 seconds
- 4.jpg: 1 second

etc.

Between the images I want to gradually fade out the old image and fade in the new image.

I have a feeling this can all be done with `convert` and `ffmpeg`. However, the problem is with having the different duration between each image. [This page](http://www.itforeveryone.co.uk/image-to-video.html) helps a lot, but I can't figure out how to time things between images. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a solution to your Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213550/how-to-create-video-with-images-and-different-time-interval-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 1):

If all of the `.jpg`  files combined can be faithfully rendered in 256 colours out of 16mln colour colour space, then you can convert them into frames of an animated gif, which allows you to specify delays per frame in 100th of seconds.

You can then use `convert` (from the `imagemagick` package) to do the conversion:

```
convert -delay 200 1.jpg -delay 600 2.jpg -delay 1000 3.jpg -delay 100 4.jpg \
    .....  result.gif
```

(replace the dots with additional "`-delay N.jpg`" pairs).

Comment: Thanks Anthon but I need the quality and colors that GIF can't offer!

Comment: It was worth a try, if there is little constraint on the size you can try [MJPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG), [APNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG) or else a real video format (MPEG, AVI). The Animated stills formats usually have some display time control, video just has N frames per second